# How do you clean a friend's buildings?

Tags: android, paradise-island

There's a new achievement in Paradise Island for cleaning a friend's buildings. How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the social button on the bottom right of the screen. Hit the friends tab, you will be taken to their island. Above three of their facilities you will see a cleaning brush. Tap each of those to receive money.