# How often can you clean a friend's buildings for Paradise Island?

Tags: paradise-island

I know [how to clean your friend's buildings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26672/8366) for the new achievement just recently added but how often does the cleaning brush appear? is it time based?

Comment: @Juan That question asks how to do it, this asks how often it can be done.  I don't see that mentioned in the other question at all.

Comment: Sorry, I misread

Answer (score 4):

It is time based. There is a maximum number of cleanings per day based on your level. After cleaning this many times, you have to wait 24 hours until you can clean their buildings again.

Comment: Thanks for answering a tough question.  Do you know how to determine the maximum number based on your level?  That would be useful to add.